# how to write python code to change display color

Tags: scripting, python

I want to change display color.

I have a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 50
xrandr --output VGA1 --gamma 1.28:1:1.28 # for purple
```

How can I write it in python?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/env python
import os
cmd1 = "sleep 50"
cmd2 = "xrandr --output VGA1 --gamma 1.28:1:1.28"   
os.system(cmd1)
os.system(cmd2)
```

Comment: Note that those two `system()`s will invoke one shell each, so it will run one additional shell command and one python command compared to the bash script.

Comment: It is just for demo purpose , how to do it in python , there are lots of other options , and optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Using `commands` module (**Preferred**):

```
from commands import getoutput
getoutput('sleep 50; xrandr --output VGA1 --gamma 1.28:1:1.28')
```

Using `os.system` module:

```
import os
os.system('sleep 50; xrandr --output VGA1 --gamma 1.28:1:1.28')
```

`os.system` will shell out and run the command without a way to capture the output. Avoid using this, even if you don't care about the output, the `commands` module is much better.

`commands` has two methods that can run and return the output:

- getoutput - will run the command and return the output
- getstatusoutput - will run the command and return the status code and the output